# Secure My ASP .NET Code For Presentation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web application , for presentation to my client they ask me to install it on their local server so they can test it , here is my question !?

Is there any way so i can publish uniquely for that server , i did put some limitation but many features in my app are open , so they can make a disk image from server and use it anywhere else ,

Is there any method to use so my web application check if this server is same server ( by hardware id or anything i don't have any idea ) then start to work !

I saw many codes but they are win forms for generating unique hid , but how can i connect done it with asp .net

**EDIT**

Could u take a look at this also ,

i am `using system.management class`

is this reliable i mean are they unique ?

```
  private string GetUniqueID()
    {
        string cpuInfo = string.Empty;
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (cpuInfo == "")
            {
                //Get only the first CPU's ID
                cpuInfo = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        ManagementObject dsk = new ManagementObject(@"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + "C" + @":""");
        dsk.Get();
        string volumeSerial = dsk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();

        string HardWareUniqueID = volumeSerial + cpuInfo;

        return HardWareUniqueID;
    }
```

Appreciate your answers,
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't trust your client, you should consider dropping them.

Comment: A question for you would be, do you not trust your client enough that you think they're going to steal it and/or not pay you? That's the problem I'd work on fixing rather than the code.

Comment: Did you even sign a contract? That's what contracts are for, never ever work without a contract.

Comment: with our without contract i don't want to let them make a fool out of me , cause this application can be used locally i can't go there anytime to checkout are they using it or not , AND suggest i just copy it on a usb drive and lost it ?! what then

Comment: If it's a web app, why do they need it installed locally on their machine to 'test'?  What's the reason they can't just use the internet and have it running on your machine?  If off-line, local access is required, then I would simply suggest the time-bomb approach that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hae a few choices...

1. Lock your web site to the single IP address you install it on. To make your life easier, check for that IP in a common page base class.  (Note, you could also write HTTP handlers, but the base-class approach is easier.)
2. Put a 'phone home' call in the app that checks with your server every time it's started up. That way you can check if they have moved it or if multiple instances are running.
3. Use the built-in licensing features of .NET (the same one third-party developers use for controls, etc.)
4. The easiest... just put in a time-bomb that lets them test it for a few weeks, then automatically blocks access.  Be smart though... persist the last-checked time so you can tell if they've rolled back their clock trying to get more usage.

Just make sure to distribute a web application, not a web project so you can distribute your code as a compiled bumary rather than having to ship the code-behind files.  That will keep prying eyes out, but does make deployment more a pain since you always have to recompile with every change (as opposed to on-demand compiling.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid having it "phone home" an alternative is to generate some kind of certificate and place it on the machine.  Use a private key that only you know to encrypt the machine name and/or IP.  Then have your app use your public key to decrypt it to verify that it is allowed to run on this server.  Nobody who doesn't know your private key will be able to create valid certificates.

Comment: as long as my application is for using inside local network , even without any internet connection i can't rely on ip or phone home , but private key is good i will take a look into it , could u also check my code in first post !?

Answer (score 0):

I would put in a time bomb. It's trivial to implement. Also, your client's won't think that you don't trust them. A fixed evaluation period in the application is extremely common.

Answer (score 0):

Provide them a VMware image without any user-access just allow them to open the website externally via HTTP in their web browser.